# Perl regex to act on a file from the command line

Tags: perl, unix

In a file, say xyz.txt i want to replace the pattern of any number followed by a dot example:1.,2.,10.,11. etc.. with a whitespace.
How to compose a perl command on the command line to act on the file to do the above, what should be the regex to be used ?

Please Help
Thank You.

Answer (score 31):

This HAS to be a Perl oneliner?

```
perl -i -pe  's/\d+\./ /g' <fileName>
```

The Perl command line options: `-i` is used to specify what happens to the input file. If you don't give it a file extension, the original file is lost and is replaced by the Perl munged output. For example, if I had this:

```
perl -i.bak -pe  's/\d+\./ /g' <fileName>
```

The original file would be stored with a `.bak` suffix and *<fileName>* itself would contain your output.

The `-p` means to enclose your Perl program in a print loop that looks **SOMEWHAT** like this:

```
while ($_ = <>) {
    <Your Perl one liner>
    print "$_";
}
```

This is a somewhat simplified explanation what's going on. You can see the actual perl loop by doing a `perldoc perlrun` from the command line. The main idea is that it allows you to act on each line of a file just like `sed` or `awk`.

The `-e` simply contains your Perl command.

You can also do file redirection too:

```
perl -pe  's/\d+\./ /g' < xyz.txt > xyz.txt.out
```

Comment: +1 for pointing out the very useful use of -i, for explaining the mechanics behind -p, and for showing the redirection alternative, all in addition to correctly answering the question.

Comment: Use double quotes "" to enclose the regexp string if you are using Active Perl in windows CMD, or it will not work. Just tested in my windows 10 command line.

Comment: I'm never using ```sed``` again. ```perl -pe``` is *it*.

Answer (score 5):

Answer (not tested):

```
perl -ipe "s/\d+\./ /g" xyz.txt
```

Comment: I personally like to type `perl -pie` because then it spells a word, but it doesn't matter.

Comment: anything after the i (except a space) is not perl option but instead what to suffix your backup file names with (a space would me for perl to not create backup files - which is what you probably want if you're in a git repository). So -pie is looking for the first following argument to be the file of perl commands you want to execute.

Answer (score 1):

Both

```
perl -ipe "s/\d+\./ /g" xyz.txt
```

and

```
perl -pie
```

cannot execute on my system.

I use the following order:

```
perl -i -pe
```