# Is there an alternative to negative look ahead in sed

Tags: regex, sed, regex-lookarounds

In `sed` I would like to be able to match `/js/` but not `/js/m` I cannot do `/js/[^m]` because that would match `/js/` plus whatever character comes after. Negative look ahead does not work in `sed`. Or I would have done `/js/(?!m)` and called it a day. Is there a way to achieve this with sed that would work for most similar situations where you want a section of text that does not end in another section of text?

Is there a better tool for what I am trying to do than sed? Possibly one that allows look ahead. `awk` seems a bit too much with its own language.

Comment: You may capture the char matched with `[^m]` and use a backreference in the replacement pattern.

Comment: Something like `sed 's#/js/\($\|[^m]\)#REPLACED\1#g'` or `sed -E 's#/js/($|[^m])#REPLACED\1#g'`

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: you can't do that with the string "/js//js/".

Comment: The method in the second comment is good, and would work for what I am looking to do. However, Casimir raises a good point.

Comment: Also is there something like sed that can handle look ahead? This question is a bit off topic but curious if anyone knows.

Comment: With sed the only way is to match what you want to avoid and then play with the replacement pattern and capture groups. For instance to make the match uppercase, you can write something like: `sed -e 's#\(/js/\)\|\(/js/m\)#\2\U\1#g'`

Comment: Or use a perl command line: `perl -e's#/js/(?!m)#rep#g'`

Comment: You can also do a substitution to protect `/js/m` then you perform your subsitution for `/js/` and you restore all `/js/m` with a last substitution.

Comment: Perl sounds like a better tool, thanks. But how would I execute that command on a file?

Comment: `perl  -e's#/js/(?!m)#rep#g' file` (exactly like sed)

Comment: The above did not work but this did: `perl -i -pe 's#/js/(?!m)#rep#g' sedtest.txt`. Thanks to [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4361004/perl-regex-to-act-on-a-file-from-the-command-line)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well you could just do this:

```
$ echo 'I would like to be able to match /js/ but not /js/m' |
    sed 's:@:@A:g; s:/js/m:@B:g; s:/js/:<&>:g; s:@B:/js/m:g; s:@A:@:g'
I would like to be able to match </js/> but not /js/m
```

You didn't say what you wanted to do with /js/ when you found it so I just put `<>` around it. That will work on all UNIX systems, unlike a perl solution since perl isn't guaranteed to be available and you're not guaranteed to be allowed to install it.

The approach I use above is a common idiom in sed, awk, etc. to create strings that can't be present in the input. It doesn't matter what character you use for `@` as long as it's not present in the string or regexp you're really interested in, which in the above is `/js/`. `s/@/@A/g` ensures that every occurrence of `@` in the input is followed by `A`. So now when I do `s/foobar/@B/g` I have replaced every occurrence of `foobar` with `@B` and I KNOW that every `@B` represents `foobar` because all other `@`s are followed by `A`. So now I can do `s/foo/whatever/` without tripping over `foo` appearing within `foobar`. Then I just unwind the initial substitutions with `s/@B/foobar/g; s/@A/@/g`.

In this case though since you aren't using multi-line hold-spaces you can do it more simply with:

```
sed 's:/js/m:\n:g; s:/js/:<&>:g; s:\n:/js/m:g'
```

since there can't be newlines in a newline-separated string. The above will only work in seds that support use of `\n` to represent a newline (e.g. GNU sed) but for portability to all seds it should be:

```
sed 's:/js/m:\
:g; s:/js/:<&>:g; s:\
:/js/m:g'
```

Comment: What are the @'s doing in this case? I am unfamiliar. They appear to be some kind of variable. Is that right?

Comment: `It doesn't matter what character you use for @ as long as it's not present in the string` and `every occurrence of @ in the input is followed by A` seem contradictory.

Comment: In what way? Please clarify.

Comment: @ has to not be in the input string. But then you say that every occurrence of @ in the input... But there should be no @ in the input.

Comment: I didn't say not in the input string, I said not in the string you're interested in (`/js/` in your case). The first `s/@/@A` is to ensure that even if `@` is present we handle it but if you were trying to find `@js@` instead of `/js/` than that substitution would turn every `@js@` in the input into `@Ajs@A` and so you'd never match on `@js@` after that substitution.

Comment: Ok, now I get it. I see that @ is just a plain old character. I was having a hard time grasping that.

Comment: In `sed 's:/js/m:\n:g; s:/js/:<&>:g; s:\n:/js/m:g'` You are squirreling away the text you do not want to edit, under the name `\n`. Then running your command on the text you want to edit. Then putting back the text you squirreled away.

Comment: I wouldn't say "under the name..." because all I'm doing is temporarily replacing the text I don't want to edit with `\n`, I'm not storing it in a variable named `\n` or anything like that, but conceptually that is correct. And yes, instead of `@` you could use `x` or `Z` or `#` or any other character you like that's not present in the string/regexp you're targeting. I tend to use a non-alphabetic character just because I'm usually interested in strings containing alphabetic characters.